# Can't transform dask.dataframe by dask.pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I want to transform dataframe by using dask.pivot_talbe.
First I group by data and get the output.

```
agg_dict = {
    'value': ['count', on_count, off_count, 'max', 'min', 'mean', 'std']
}
df = dd.read_csv(filename, engine='python')
df = df.groupby(['addr', 'timestamp']).agg(agg_dict)

df.compute()
```

Then, I want to use pivot_table to reform the dataframe.

```
df.pivot_table(index='timestamp', columns='addr', values='value')
```

get error:

> ValueError: 'columns' must be the name of an existing column

how to fix it?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible: you should give an example with a small DataFrame that gives an idea of your data.

Comment: also show the output you'd like to have

Answer (score 1):

As the message suggests, you will want `addr` to be a column, but after groupby, it will be part of the index, so you need

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

before the pivot.

Note that this has nothing to do with Dask, because you have called `compute()`, giving you a normal Pandas data-frame.